# Showing name field in header and in edit

Tags: usability, forms, navigation

I have a small query regarding this design

[image]

The right panel shows details of the left panel and the Header title of panel is same as that in field. Is it okay from UX point of view?

Comment: One might expect the Role Name to change once edited in the input field and the Save button is pressed (but maybe that doesn't happen?). You have not provided any information about that. If you would like answers that take the time to explain UX in depth, please take the time to include necessary information (information that is obviously missing) as well as complementary extra information to establish context when asking Questions.

Comment: Yea the name will be changed and saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only "okay" because it introduces redundancy and violates the "you can change what you see where you see it"-idea.

A better design would be to allow the change of the title in place. If you have a special edit mode, as indicated by Save/Cancel at the bottom, you'll need an input field with the title font.

If you wouldn't have the edit mode, I've seen the following solution: Hovering the title displays a pen icon, clicking the pen turns the title into an input field.

Answer (score 4):

Having a title is important to keep the user informed and connected to the navigation. It works as a feedback and guides the user in moving forward or backward. In the image, the title is helping the user know that he/she has opened the right page when the particular option is selected from the nav menu.

A header is also important from accessibility point of view such as when using a screen reader.